# Arpeggiated Chords with Partial Wavy Vertical Lines

Tags: theory, piano, chords, notation, technique

Does anyone know how to play an arpeggiated chord when the wavy vertical line beside the chord is not all the way alongside the chord?

Any fingering suggestions for playing the first chord?

Thank you :)

[image]

Here are more of such chords coming next in the piece:

[image]

Comment: It is called a rolled chord. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MjE0olNlBEg

Comment: Especially combined with i.stack.imgur.com/MtjQz.jpg, I can't tell if this is just sloppy arpeggio notation or not.

Comment: I think that whoever wrote this was a bit lazy and didn't bother placing the wavy lines exactly where they should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fingering for this instance**

For the first chord, play the B E G and B with your left hand, and the upper E and G with your right. Like this:

```
X:1
K:Emin
M:4/4
L:1/2
[V:V1] [eg]
[V:V2 clef=bass] !arpeggio![B,EGB]
```

**How to play**

How rolled chords are played allows room for interpretation in regard to whether the unrolled, simultaneous note(s) are played at the beginning or end of the roll.

**Is this a thing?**

Yes, but it's usually written as separate chords, one rolled and one not. For example, see the chords in the *Poco più lento* section of Chopin's [Nocturne in C minor](https://imslp.simssa.ca/files/imglnks/usimg/0/04/IMSLP48578-PMLP02308-Chopin_Nocturnes_Schirmer_Mikuli_Op_48.pdf), Op. 48 No. 1. In that section's fifth measure, there is a rolled chord in the left hand, but a block chord in the right. The reverse is true in Scott Joplin's "[Crush Collision March](https://imslp.simssa.ca/files/imglnks/usimg/1/14/IMSLP534939-PMLP13293-Crush_Collision_March.pdf)", wherein there are several instances of right-hand rolled chords against left-hand block chords.

The problem in the score you've encountered is that the chords are written such that they have the appearance of "partially rolled" chords. However, they're just two chords in which one is rolled and the other is not. In either of the above cases, just put both hands on a single stem, and you have exactly the same thing.

Comment: Thank you Aaron for your reply. I don't believe it is a printing problem though. The lines are at different lengths for other chords in the piece as well. Here's what comes next. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtjQz.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtjQz.jpg)

Comment: @Sherri That clarifies things. I've updated my post to remove that comment and replace it with a comment on how to execute the chord. Much appreciated if you would accept and/or upvote the answer if you found it useful. That's the best thanks you can give here on SE. (To "accept", click the check mark at the left of the answer; to upvote, click the upward pointing triangle at the left of the answer.) Welcome to the site.

Comment: Accept & upvote done! Thanks again. I was wondering if there is such a thing as partial arpeggiated chord in music in which some notes are played rolled and others solid. I'd never seen such chords before. For playing the first chord, shouldn't I play the top two notes together at the same time I start playing the first note of the LH (B) and hold them instead of playing them together after the top B?

Comment: @Sherri I've expanded my answer in light of your comments. I suggest you also expand your question to include the excerpt you linked to in the comments as well as to include your more detailed question. Comments can be deleted. Thanks for the accept. Very much appreciated.